# JOIN based on columns and show results for both non matching and matching rows in a view

Tags: sql, join, case

I am planning to join 3 tables together using inner join and case .

Background: I am trying to first join `device` and `devicemessage` table linking by deviceid.

Next was to link the first 2 tables to the `timetable` table using the `roomid` and also `classstartdate` and `classenddate` columns.

I want it to show rows which matches both roomid and also `localtime` column from `devicemessage` table to be between `ClassStartDate` and `ClassEndDate` from `timetable table.

I know that since inner join only displays matching rows, I also want my view to show those rows  combined `device` and `devicemessage` tables which `localtime` column value is not between `classstartdate` and `classenddate` from `timetable` table. With the columns from the `Timetable` table being null or empty in the view.

> Device table has these columns : RoomID, RoomName ,DeviceID
>
> DeviceMessageTable has these columns : DeviceID , Occupancy , LocalTime
>
> Timetable has these columns : SubjectCode , Day , ClassStartDate , ClassEndDate , RoomID

The code that I currently have:

```sql
Create View v_ClassroomOccupancy
AS
Select A.[RoomCode],A.[RoomName],A.[DeviceID],
         B.[Occupancy],B.[LocalTime],
           C.[CLASSGROUP],C.[DAY], C.[CLASSSTARTDATE], C.[CLASSENDDATE], C.[DURATION],

CASE
WHEN (B.LocalTime BETWEEN C.CLASSSTARTDATE AND C.CLASSENDDATE) 
    AND B.Occupancy = 1 THEN 'Booked And Occupied'
WHEN (B.LocalTime NOT BETWEEN C.CLASSSTARTDATE AND C.CLASSENDDATE) 
    AND B.Occupancy = 1 THEN 'Not Booked but Occupied'
WHEN (B.LocalTime BETWEEN C.CLASSSTARTDATE AND C.CLASSENDDATE)
    AND B.Occupancy = 0 THEN 'Booked but Not Occupied'
ELSE 'Not booked and Not Occupied' 
END AS ClassroomStatus

From Device A
INNER JOIN DeviceMessageHistory B ON  B.DeviceID=A.DeviceID
INNER JOIN ClassTimeTable C ON  (B.LocalTime between C.CLASSSTARTDATE and C.CLASSENDDATE) WHERE C.ROOMID = A.RoomCode;
```

I tried this but the result was an empty table.

Comment: Read about outer join. This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Google your title.

Comment: Oh sweet outer join. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `left join`, but it should be phrased as:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM Device d JOIN
     DeviceMessageHistory dmh
     ON  dmh.DeviceID = d.DeviceID JOIN
     ClassTimeTable ctt
     ON dmh.LocalTime BETWEEN ctt.CLASSSTARTDATE AND ctt.CLASSENDDATE AND
        ctt.ROOMID = d.RoomCode
```

Note:  The logic in the `WHERE` clause needs to move to the `ON` clause.

I also changed the table aliases.  Learn to use *meaningful* table aliases (table abbreviations) rather than arbitrary letters.

Comment: So instead of using left join, just use full join?

Comment: @JamesFrancoHadi . . . I don't understand your comment.  You should use the appropriate `join` for the tables involved.

Comment: @JamesFrancoHadi . . . That would suggest that nothing matches the `join` conditions.  Your code doesn't have a `where`, so the only filtering is the `on` conditions.